# Plant.js file not found when using an example from Sencha Docs website

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am having an error when I use an example from the Sencha Docs website. The example is a grid which you can find [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#cell-editing)

So I tried to copy all the code, but for some reason it does not work for me.

`app.js`

```
    const test = Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.CellEditing', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        requires: [
            'Ext.selection.CellModel',
            'Ext.grid.*',
            'Ext.data.*',
            'Ext.util.*',
            'Ext.form.*',
            'KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant'
        ],
        xtype: 'cell-editing',


        title: 'Edit Plants',
        frame: true,

        initComponent: function() {
            this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
                clicksToEdit: 1
            });

            Ext.apply(this, {
                width: 680,
                height: 350,
                plugins: [this.cellEditing],
                store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant,
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        // load remote data using HTTP
                        url: 'resources/data/grid/plants.xml',
                        // specify a XmlReader (coincides with the XML format of the returned data)
                        reader: {
                            type: 'xml',
                            // records will have a 'plant' tag
                            record: 'plant'
                        }
                    },
                    sorters: [{
                        property: 'common',
                        direction:'ASC'
                    }]
                }),
                columns: [{
                    header: 'Common Name',
                    dataIndex: 'common',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor: {
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                }, {
                    header: 'Light',
                    dataIndex: 'light',
                    width: 130,
                    editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
                        typeAhead: true,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        store: [
                            ['Shade','Shade'],
                            ['Mostly Shady','Mostly Shady'],
                            ['Sun or Shade','Sun or Shade'],
                            ['Mostly Sunny','Mostly Sunny'],
                            ['Sunny','Sunny']
                        ]
                    })
                }, {
                    header: 'Price',
                    dataIndex: 'price',
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'right',
                    renderer: 'usMoney',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 100000
                    }
                }, {
                    header: 'Available',
                    dataIndex: 'availDate',
                    width: 95,
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('M d, Y'),
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        format: 'm/d/y',
                        minValue: '01/01/06',
                        disabledDays: [0, 6],
                        disabledDaysText: 'Plants are not available on the weekends'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                    header: 'Indoor?',
                    dataIndex: 'indoor',
                    width: 90,
                    stopSelection: false
                }, {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: false,
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    items: [{
                        icon: 'resources/images/icons/fam/delete.gif',
                        tooltip: 'Delete Plant',
                        scope: this,
                        handler: this.onRemoveClick
                    }]
                }],
                selModel: {
                    selType: 'cellmodel'
                },
                tbar: [{
                    text: 'Add Plant',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onAddClick
                }]
            });

            this.callParent();

            this.on('afterlayout', this.loadStore, this, {
                delay: 1,
                single: true
            })
        },

        loadStore: function() {
            this.getStore().load({
                // store loading is asynchronous, use a load listener or callback to handle results
                callback: this.onStoreLoad
            });
        },

        onStoreLoad: function(){
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Store Load Callback',
                msg: 'store was loaded, data available for processing',
                icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        },

        onAddClick: function(){
            // Create a model instance
            var rec = new KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant({
                common: 'New Plant 1',
                light: 'Mostly Shady',
                price: 0,
                availDate: Ext.Date.clearTime(new Date()),
                indoor: false
            });

            this.getStore().insert(0, rec);
            this.cellEditing.startEditByPosition({
                row: 0, 
                column: 0
            });
        },

        onRemoveClick: function(grid, rowIndex){
            this.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
        }
    })
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items: [{
                    items: test
                }]
            })
        }
    })
```

`index.html`:

```
<html> 
  <head>
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- <link rel='shortcut icon' href='./imatges/icones/petits/login.png' type='image/png'> -->

        <title>Sencha</title>

        <!-- CDN 4.2.1- NEPTUNE -->
        <link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
        <link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

I keep getting this error when I open it on the browser:
[image]

Why is it not working and how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the `CellEditing` and `model.grid.Plant` with the app name of `KitchenSink`:

```
const test = Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.CellEditing',{
 //rest of your code

requires: [
            //other requires
            'KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant'
        ]
store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant,
                    //rest of store

onAddClick: function(){
            // Create a model instance
            var rec = new KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant({
                //rest of model configs
```

But in the `Ext.application`, you define the name of the application as "MyApp":

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    //other configs
```

Change the name of the application to KitchenSink or define the `CellEditing`, the requires and the models like:

```
const test = Ext.define('MyApp.view.grid.CellEditing',{
     //rest of your code
```

And see if it works.

Comment: I have just tried to change the name to KitchenSink and the issue persists, but it has a different dc number now: https://i.imgur.com/F3aP9Ww.png

Comment: It seems you don't have the `KitchenSink.model.grid.Plant` model in your app, you have to define it somewhere, you're just referencing it, but not defining it

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the issue, I have defined it and it works now. However, it does not work completly, I know how to fix the first error, but I am getting an error when I click on Add plant. Do you know why? https://i.imgur.com/c3jPApl.png

Comment: How's your store data? it's pointing to `'resources/data/grid/plants.xml'`, do you have that file? add a listener to storeload and check if the data is loaded correctly

Comment: No, I do not have that file. Do you know if I can find it somewhere? I just copied the code from the examples website and the files were not included... I also do not know what sctructure must have.

Comment: First, you need to understand how stores work in Extjs, read about it in the [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store), I think you can find this specific store file in some repository in [github](https://github.com/pguerrant/ext-kitchensink-theme/blob/master/resources/data/grid/plants.xml)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have loaded its data and now it works perfectly!